# how can you programmatically analyze flash content?

Tags: flash

How can I verify that flash content includes or excludes certain text?

Comment: Can you provide some more detail or some context? For instance, are you attempting to read text from outside of a compiled SWF or from within the source?

Comment: both scenarios are of interest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no straight forward way of doing that. In fact, that was primarily the problem for Flash based sites with respect to SEO. Search engines couldn't index the flash based sites. But Adobe recently released [Flash Reader Technology](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/swf_searchability.html) to make the flash/flex based sites indexable. You probably want to look at it and see if it helps you.